# Using contains method to avoid duplicates

Tags: java, list

I am creating a List that converts a List of Observations(Registration registration, Time time) into a List containing only Registrations, however this list cannot contain duplicates and I'm battling to ensure that duplicates don't occur.

```
public List<Registration> getVehicles(){
    List<Registration> rtnList = new ArrayList<Registration>();
    for (Observation obs:observationsList){
        if (rtnList.contains(obs.getIdentifier())){
        }
        else
            rtnList.add(obs.getIdentifier());
    }
    return rtnList;
}
```

This is what I have got, but duplicates still occur.

With observations such as the following:

```
obsList.record (new Registration("CA 976-543"), new Time("13:15:03"));
obsList.record (new Registration("BCD 123 MP"), new Time("13:21:47"));
obsList.record (new Registration("CA 976-543"), new Time("13:35:50"));
```

The .equals() method for the Registration class is:

```
public boolean equals(Registration other){
    if (getIdentifier().equals(other.getIdentifier()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I would like the output of obsList.getVehicles to be :

> [CA 976-543, BCD 123 MP]

But instead I am getting:

> [CA 976-543, BCD 123 MP, CA 976-543]

Comment: what does  `getIdentifier()` do? This may be the cause of your error.

Comment: `getIdentifier()` returns the Registration portion of the Observation.

Comment: Can't you just make it a Set of Registrations?

Comment: Can you share the ObversationList code?

Comment: Can you share `Registration`'s code? Specifically, are you overriding the `equals` method?

Comment: did you override `.equals` method in `Registration` class and `Time` class? because `.contains()` method internally use `.equals()`

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using .contains()?

Comment: Please post the equals code in the question section so it's formatted and visible. Also without this being correct your code will never work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `contains` method uses the elements' `equals` method. For lists, it essentially iterates over all the elements of the list and checks if that element is equal to the value passed.

According to your last comment, you haven't properly overridden it. [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) takes an `Obejct` argument. In fact, instead of **overriding** the method, you've **overloaded** it. Using the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation would have, in fact, caused a compilation error on this method and made the mistake clearer:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) { // Note the argument type
    if (!(o instanceof Registration)) {
        return false;
    }
    Registration other = (Registration) o;
    return getIdentifier().equals(other.getIdentifier()) && 
           getProvince().equals(other.getProvince());    
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks for the help! I think I was using the incorrect argument type which wasn't allowing me to override.

Comment: That said, a hashset would probably be the better choice here. `contains` using `equals` on an `ArrayList` is going to be an `O(n)` lookup, vs on a hashset you could get close to `O(1)` by evaluating just the hash.